# После восстановления из savedInstanceState не удаляются дочерние вьюшки из LinearLayout

Tags: android, kotlin

У меня динамический список полей ввода. Т.е. в зависимости от выбора пользователя определённых значений выводится список полей ввода. Поэтому мне пришлось эти поля (EditText) добавлять программно в пустой LinearLayout, который я специально разместил в разметке. Код добавляется в определённый момент (когда пользователь в спинере выбрал нужную категорию). Код создания полей ввода такой:

```kotlin
    fun generateAdditionalFields(fields: ArrayList<String>) {
        tempAdditionalFields.removeAll(tempAdditionalFields)
        var isFirst = true
        fields.forEach {
            tempAdditionalFields.add(makeEditText(it, it, isFirst))
            isFirst = false
        }
        additional_fields_block.removeAllViews()
        tempAdditionalFields.forEach {
            additional_fields_block.addView(it)
        }
    }

    fun makeEditText(hint: String, name: String, first: Boolean) : EditText {
        val editText = EditText(ContextThemeWrapper(this, R.style.MainInput), null, 0)
        editText.hint = hint
        editText.layoutParams = LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT)
        editText.tag = name
        if (!first) editText.setMargin(topMargin = dpToPix(5f))
        return editText
    }
```

У меня также есть список для хранения этих полей ввода `tempAdditionalFields`, чтобы потом можно было сохранить введённые пользователем данные.

Когда пользователь переключает категорию, то старые поля ввода удаляются (как из списка, так и из `LinearLayout`) и генерируются заново.

Всё работало без проблем. Но я решил модифицировать код и сохранять данные при повороте экрана устройства, и восстанавливать их после пересоздания активити. Обычно с этой операцией проблем не возникает. Но в данном случае  после пересоздания активити я восстанавливаю список `tempAdditionalFields`, а потом из него добавляю все `EditText` обратно в LinearLayout, но тогда выдаёт ошибку, что мол там уже содержатся эти вью. Тогда я вызываю перед добавлением `additional_fields_block.removeAllViews()`, и всё равно вылетает та же ошибка. Затем я убрал добавление. Но на экран выводятся совершенно новые поля ввода. Да это те поля ввода, которые были до пересоздания активити, но без введённого текста. Хотя в восстановленном списке `tempAdditionalFields` введённый текст есть. Я для эксперимента вообще убрал восстановление этого списка. И убрал даже добавление этих полей ввода после восстановления. Результат был тем же. И что самое интересное, метод `additional_fields_block.removeAllViews()` не работает после пересоздания. Вернее если я его вызываю в `onCreate` или `onStart` или `onResume`. Зато если создать кнопку и повесить на неё слушателя, и при нажатии задать это самое удаление вьюшек, то при клике оно удаляет как надо.

Весь код публиковать не стал, так как его очень много. Но вот некоторые части.

onCreate:

```kotlin
    var step = 1
    var avatar_id : Int? = null
    var tempAdditionalFields = LinkedList<EditText>()
    var companies = LinkedList<Company>()
    val companiesAdapter = CompaniesShortListAdapter(companies)
    var dontSwitchFields = false

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_create_user)
        if (!restoreFromSavedInstance(savedInstanceState)){
            GetCompaniesListTask().execute()
        } else dontSwitchFields = true
        switchUserInfoBtnsVis()
        switchFirmNameBtnsVis()
        switchChooseRoleBtnsVis()
        setListeners()
        switchStep(step)
    }
```

Методы сохранения и восстановления (тут я изменил и закомментил для эксперимента некоторые строки):

```kotlin
    override fun onSaveInstanceState(outState: Bundle?) {
        outState?.let {bundle ->
            bundle.putInt("step", step)
            avatar_id?.let { bundle.putInt("avatar_id", it) }

            bundle.putSerializable("tempAdditionalFields", tempAdditionalFields)
            bundle.putSerializable("companies", companies)
        }
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState)
    }

    fun restoreFromSavedInstance(savedInstanceState: Bundle?): Boolean {
        savedInstanceState?.let { bundle ->
            step = bundle.getInt("step")
switchStep(step)
            avatar_id = bundle.getInt("avatar_id")
//            tempAdditionalFields.removeAll(tempAdditionalFields)
//            tempAdditionalFields.addAll(bundle.getSerializable("tempAdditionalFields") as Collection<EditText>)
/*            tempAdditionalFields.forEach {
                Log.e("TEST_EDIT", "edit: ${it.text}")
            }*/
            additional_fields_block.removeAllViews()
            companies.removeAll(companies)
            companies.addAll(bundle.getSerializable("companies") as Collection<Company>)
            companiesAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
            return true
        }
        return false
    }
```

Я понимаю так, что система сама восстанавливает эти добавленные вью. Но тогда на каком этапе? И я понимаю что в данном случае можно было бы пойти другим путём и просто сохранить введённые в поля данные, а потом снова заполнить. Но хотелось бы докопаться до истины, почему я не могу удалить добавленные перед поворотом экрана вьюшки (`EditText`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В общем как оказалось проблема была сразу в двух местах. Если вкратце они были:

1. В спиннере
2. В способе удаления вьюшек

Теперь подробнее, вдруг кому пригодится.

### 1. Спиннер

У меня на спиннере был слушатель, в котором я обрабатывал метод `onItemSelected`. При срабатывании этого метода я вызывал генерацию полей ввода. Т.е. в зависимости от выбранной категории создавались свои `EditText` и каждый раз своё количество. Но я не подумал, что при инициализации списка категорий в спиннере этот метод так же срабатывает. Т.е. как только список категорий (или адаптер) подключается к спиннеру, то срабатывает этот метод.

Когда я это понял, то изменил подход. Я создал переменную, которая хранит позицию выбранной категории в спиннере и по умолчанию равна 0. И при срабатывании метода `onItemSelected` я делаю проверку совпадает ли значение этой переменной с новой позицией. Если не совпадает, значит пользователь сменил категорию, и тогда сохраняем новую позицию в эту переменную и выполняем нужный нам метод по генерации полей ввода.

Я сохраняю и восстанавливаю эту переменную при смене экрана. И делаю это из метода onCreate до того как спиннер восстановится. Поэтому когда спиннер восстановится и установит старую позицию то она будет совпадать с восстановленной переменной и генерации полей ввода не произойдёт.

Это решило проблему, когда вьюшки воссоздавались с нуля. Но оставалась проблема ошибки `java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.`

### 2. Удаление вьюшек

Если я обращаюсь напрямую к вьюшке, в которой содержатся поля ввода и вызываю `removeAllViews()`, а потом пытаюсь добавить поля ввода то вылетает та самая ошибка. Я сначала понимал её текст как "родительская вью уже содержит эту дочернюю вью, удалите сначала её из родителя". Но оказалось смысл несколько иной "Дочерняя вью уже имеет родителя. Сначала вызовите метод `removeView()` у родителя дочерней вью."

Хотя и кажется что два эти предложения имеют одинаковый смысл, но это не совсем так. Сначала я пытался вызвать этот метод у вьюшки напрямую, передавая ей каждый `EditText` из восстановленного массива по-отдельности. Но это не работало.

Но оказалось что по всей видимости `EditText`'ы принадлежат старому `additional_fields_block` (вьюшка `LinearLayout`), а у нового нет дочерних вью. Поэтому их родитель не новый `additional_fields_block`, а старый. И старый `additional_fields_block` всё ещё существует в памяти, так как ссылка на него имеется в `EditText`. Тогда я создал такой метод:

```kotlin
    fun restoreAdditionalFields(){
        tempAdditionalFields.forEach {
            (it.parent as ViewGroup).removeView(it)
            additional_fields_block.addView(it)
        }
    }
```

Т.е. я достаю предка из каждого текстового поля и удаляю это текстовое поле оттуда, а после добавляю его в новый `additional_fields_block`. По крайней мере я всё это понял так. Возможно мои догадки неверны, тогда прошу поправьте меня. Интересно узнать как на самом деле работает этот механизм.

Правда из onCreate мой метод не работал (ошибка не возникала, но и эффекта он не оказывал). Тогда я засунул его вызов в этот метод:

```kotlin
    override fun onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState)
        restoreAdditionalFields()
    }
```

Не совсем конечно понимаю почему так. Может кто объяснит?